# Is 50 minutes enough to get from EWR terminal C to terminal A (international arrival)?

Tags: international-travel, short-connections, ewr

I am arriving on United from Mumbai into terminal C, and have a domestic connection (also United) from terminal A 50 minutes later. What are the chances that I can make it from C to A in time, given that I am arriving internationally (will have to clear immigration). I will have only hand luggage, but I assume I will still have to clear security a second time.

Comment: I'd say practically zero. Did United actually sell you this?!

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Comment: The International to Domestic MCT (minimum connection time) used to be 1h30 at EWR. I don’t have access to more recent data so I don’t know if they changed it. If UA sold it as a single booking, they believe it’s possible, and will normally rebook your on the next available flight if you don’t make it. But of course depending on the destination and time of day it could be quite a long time after that. If UA didn’t sell it then you are on your own and if you miss the second flight you will be considered a no show, and in most cases your booking (and subsequent ones on the ticket) cancelled.

Comment: The flight from Mumbai lands at 5:40 am (if on time). I’ve looked up flights departing at 6:30am (FLL, LAS, ORD tomorrow for instance), and google flights won’t sell me a connection to those, so it seems this is below MCT and ticketed separately, is that correct? Then just forget about it.

Comment: Also note that the BOM-EWR flight is routinely late.

Comment: Snowballs chance in hell to make that connection I am surprised they even sold it to you? Is it on the same ticket?

Comment: If it is in the same ticket: do not worry (but...). It happened to me to miss the flight (long immigration queue, plus late arrival). you will get put in the next flight. BUT: same ticket, and if the next flight is full, you have to wait more... Good: intercontinental flights often arrive earlier (the timetable are often on bad side of probabilities [weather, deicing [nof from Mumbay]...])

Comment: At terminal B my plane was at the gate 9.15PM in May 2019. I was in one of the front rows. I just made the train departure around 10.25PM. This was with a second time ESTA, but those lines didn't feel quicker than the first time ones.